# How do I estimate the probability of a Carrington-level coronal mass ejection (CME) hitting the Earth?

Tags: sun, solar-system, geomagnetism, magnetohydrodynamics

I have seen some material which estimates the probability of Earth being struck by a Carrington-level CME over some time into the future. These estimates seem to be derived from historical data of CME events which *actually hit or nearly hit the Earth*.

I am curious about the distribution of matter and radiation in a single CME event.

Given that a Carrington-level CME has happened *somewhere on the surface of the sun*, what is the probability of it actually hitting the Earth? I'm talking about a "direct hit" insofar as it would cause widespread damage.

Comment: I wrote an answer on the AstronomySE at [http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/16787/13663](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/16787/13663) that discusses this briefly.  The rate of occurrence is **~12% per decade**, as estimated by doi:[10.1029/2011SW000734](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2011SW000734/abstract).

Comment: I am not interested in the probability of *some* event occurring, but the probability that any give event qualifies.

Answer (score 2):

Most [Solar coronal mass ejections (CME)](http://www.ecology.com/2014/05/01/earths-greatest-threat-cmes/) do not hit the Earth.  Only about 30 per year hit Earth, and most of these are not direct hits.

During the decade 1996 to 2006, 11,032 CMEs were observed.  About ten percent were [halo events](http://spaceweather.com/glossary/halocmes.html), or CMEs directed toward the Earth.  Only about 118 of these halo events were associated with [X-class solar flares](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/sunearth/news/X-class-flares.html), the biggest flares.

The question the OP is asking is summarized in one of his comments, below: *"Suppose the Sun only ever emitted one CME in the course of its entire lifetime, and the magnitude of that CME was on par with Carrington. What is the probability that the Earth is hit, in that single instance, and that the hit is "direct" enough to cause serious damage?"*

If a Carrington-level direct hit would require the Earth to be exactly in the center of the CME's expanding wavefront, the probability may be calculated as follows:

The surface area of the Sun is [6.079 * 10^12 square kilometers](http://solarsystem.nasa.gov/planets/sun/facts).  The diameter of the Earth is about [12,700 kilometers](http://www.universetoday.com/15055/diameter-of-earth/), which would make its cross-section in outline presented to the Sun about 126.7 * 10^6 square kilometers.

If a Carrington [CME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coronal_mass_ejection#Physical_properties) flared up at a random point and at any random instant of time on the Sun's surface, it would have roughly a (126.7 * 10^6 / 6.1 * 10^12) = **2.1 * 10^-5** probability of scoring a direct hit on the Earth.

This calculation assumes that the chance of a Carrington CME on the equator of the Sun in the plane of the Solar System is neither greater nor less than the chance of a Carrington CME occurring elsewhere on the Sun.

Also assumed is that the [CME](http://www.swpc.noaa.gov/phenomena/coronal-mass-ejections) disperses as it leaves the Sun, covering a larger area at the radius of Earth from Sun, which provides a larger area for the Earth to fall within, but proportionally the same as the area of the CME on the surface of the Sun.  Implicit in this assumption is that a Carrington event occurs only if the Earth is directly in the center of that area, which may not be the case, given [Pete Riley's](https://www.wired.com/2012/02/massive-solar-flare/) much larger probability computed from observations, which is linked below.

This is not the probability of two independent events: (1) CME occurs, and (2) Earth receives a direct hit.  The OP states that the CME has already occurred, so this is only the probability that Earth receives a direct hit.  If this were considered as two independent events, the probability of (1) should be multiplied by the probability of (2).

This probability is a great deal less than the 12% chance of a Carrington CME hitting the Earth per decade that [Pete Riley](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2011SW000734/abstract) estimated from historical data.  You can see his method in [this presentation he made to the Space Studies Board](http://sites.nationalacademies.org/cs/groups/ssbsite/documents/webpage/ssb_153147.pdf).

Coronal mass ejections consist of eruptions from "ropes" of [twisted magnetic field that extend out of the Sun's surface like kinks in a phone cord](http://earthsky.org/space/what-are-coronal-mass-ejections).  If the magnetic field kinks too much, it bursts.  Plasma in the ejections is composed of protons and electrons existing as independent charged particles.  It's accompanied by ionizing radiation such as X-rays.

Comment: Your calculation seems to model the CME as a point rather than a splodge, and does not take distance to earth and dispersion into account. (If the earth was twice as far away it would have an equal chance of being hit but not an equal chance of being hit by a concentration of matter/radiation). Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @spraff : You are correct that I do not address the solar area involved in a single CME.  The question says "somewhere on the surface of the sun", so  even if a CME covered an entire hemisphere, given the OP's parameters, the probability wouldn't change.  Dispersion also shouldn't be a factor, considering that the CME originates at the surface of the Sun, not on the dispersed surface area at the Earth's radius from the Sun.  This assumes that the area covered by the CME gets larger as it moves farther from the Sun.

Comment: [Dispersion matters](http://i.imgur.com/X5EJOoZ.png) otherwise we'd get geomagnetic storms from CMEss on other stars.

Comment: @spraff : Yes, the CME disperses as it leaves the Sun.  Therefore the intensity of the solar storm is less at the radius of the Earth.  But the probability of Earth being within that area is the same.  The area covered by the CME at the radius of Earth from Sun is proportionally the same as the area covered by the CME at the surface of the Sun (ceteris paribus), so computed probability of Earth being within the area of the CME is the same whether computed at the dispersed spherical surface area or at the surface of the Sun.

Comment: @Ernie - The 12% rate of occurrence is per decade from Pete's paper, not our lifetimes (presumably longer than 10 years, I hope).  I posted his published work doi in a comment above.

Comment: @spraff : The probability I computed is the probability of the Earth being within the dispersed shadow of a CME, given that a CME has occurred somewhere on the surface of the Sun, which was the OP's question.  I changed the answer based on your new comment.

Comment: @honeste_vivere :  You are correct.  I re-read his presentation and changed the answer.

Comment: @Ernie my question is: what is the probability of being hit *intensely enough* to produce comparable damage.

Comment: @spraff : Your question said, "Given that a Carrington-level CME has happened..." My answer does not assess the probability of your 'Given'.  But based on Pete Riley's interpretation of past observations, there's a 12% probability of comparable damage, in a 10 year period: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/2011SW000734/abstract.  As the abstract says, Carrington events "are difficult to study, their rates of occurrence are difficult to estimate, and prediction of a specific future event is virtually impossible." At this time, 12% per decade is his best estimate, with a lot of caveats.

Comment: @Ernie you are answering a different question to the one I asked. I'm not interested in the frequency of events.

Comment: @spraff :  Number of Carrington-CMEs / number of all CMEs ?  Is that the probability you want to know?

Comment: @Ernie Suppose the Sun only ever emitted one CME in the course of its entire lifetime, and the magnitude of that CME was on par with Carrington. What it the probability that the Earth is hit, in that single instance, and that the hit is "direct" enough to cause serious damage?

Comment: @spraff : I changed the answer and included your comment, above.  A 0.000021 chance seems to be what you are looking for.  A major assumption is that the Earth must be in the center of the expanding CME wavefront to sustain Carrington-level damage.